# How can I programmatically check whether a keyboard is present in iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard

I need to check the condition of keyboard visibility in my iOS app.

Pseudocode:

```
if(keyboardIsPresentOnWindow) {
    //Do action 1
}
else if (keyboardIsNotPresentOnWindow) {
    //Do action 2
}
```

How can I check this condition?

Comment: What app? What language? What platform? My best guess is iPhone?

Comment: Question fixed.  Let the games begin!

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4374515/3196455)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52417737/7276810

Answer (score 76):

…or take the easy way:

When you enter a textField, it becomes *first responder* and the keyboard appears. 
You can check the status of the keyboard with `[myTextField isFirstResponder]`. If it returns `YES`, then the the keyboard is active.

Comment: Good solution, however this will NOT work, if a hardware keyboard is used (not unusual on the iPad).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. This tells you if the text field is the first responder. I have a view controller with multiple child view controllers, all of which contain UITextFields. Using this method, i cannot tell from my parent view controller whether the keyboard is shown. The only reliable way is to use the notification method explained in the other answers

Answer (score 66):

drawnonward's code is very close, but collides with UIKit's namespace and could be made easier to use.

```
@interface KeyboardStateListener : NSObject {
    BOOL _isVisible;
}
+ (KeyboardStateListener *)sharedInstance;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, getter=isVisible) BOOL visible;
@end

static KeyboardStateListener *sharedInstance;

@implementation KeyboardStateListener

+ (KeyboardStateListener *)sharedInstance
{
    return sharedInstance;
}

+ (void)load
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    [pool release];
}

- (BOOL)isVisible
{
    return _isVisible;
}

- (void)didShow
{
    _isVisible = YES;
}

- (void)didHide
{
    _isVisible = NO;
}

- (id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
        [center addObserver:self selector:@selector(didShow) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
        [center addObserver:self selector:@selector(didHide) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: Why does it need its own pool?

Comment: `+load` is a special method called by the Objective-C runtime. It is called for each class after the app binary loads, but before the `main()` function is entered. There is no guarantee that an autorelease pool will be live.

Comment: Thanks! The code helps me to understand Objective-c more. BTW, is there a reason for choosing `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` instead of `UIKeyboardDidHideNotification`?

Comment: No reason. "Will" notifications occur as something is about to happen. "Did" notifications occur after they've happened (usually after the animation has completed)

Comment: @rpetrich, this looks good, but I think you can delete the `+ load` function. Why does it need its own autorelease pool? I don't see `autorelease` being called anywhere. And, if we call `[UIKeyboardListener sharedInstance]` from `applicationDidFinishLaunching` as drawnonward suggests, the `main()` function will have already created one.

Comment: MattDiPasquale: If the +load method is deleted, sharedInstance will never be initialized. Since there is no guarantee that an autorelease pool is active when the runtime invokes a +load method, wrapping all calls to system-provided classes is necessary in case they call autorelease.

Comment: Nice answer!  I know this is several years old but the `NSAutoreleasePool` `alloc`/`release` can now be replaced by surrounding the code in `@autoreleasepool { }`

Comment: Don't forget to remove the Observer, probably in KeyboardStateListener's dealloc.

Comment: @Jacob KeyboardStateListener doesn't have a dealloc because it's an immortal singleton.

Comment: Works great, but you should use `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` instead of `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` if you want to move any view parallel to the keyboard.

Comment: Why isn't it a subclass of NSObject? (great answer by the way)

Comment: Very bad singleton initialization, better use [Chris solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20019834/829155).

Comment: @ArtFeel: That solution doesn't handle cases where the first attempt to query the keyboard visibility status is after the keyboard is already visible. That's a sharp edge where there need not be one.

Answer (score 34):

Create a `UIKeyboardListener` when you know the keyboard is not visible, for example by calling `[UIKeyboardListener shared]` from `applicationDidFinishLaunching`.

```
@implementation UIKeyboardListener

+ (UIKeyboardListener) shared {
    static UIKeyboardListener sListener;    
    if ( nil == sListener ) sListener = [[UIKeyboardListener alloc] init];

    return sListener;
}

-(id) init {
    self = [super init];

    if ( self ) {
        NSNotificationCenter        *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
        [center addObserver:self selector:@selector(noticeShowKeyboard:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
        [center addObserver:self selector:@selector(noticeHideKeyboard:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
    }

    return self;
}

-(void) noticeShowKeyboard:(NSNotification *)inNotification {
    _visible = true;
}

-(void) noticeHideKeyboard:(NSNotification *)inNotification {
    _visible = false;
}

-(BOOL) isVisible {
    return _visible;
}

@end
```

Comment: Note: You can use `+(void)load` to call init on this listener class so that it will generically work as a drag-and-drop into any project and initialize from the second app launches rather than you having to remember to init it anywhere.

Answer (score 33):

I think you need to use the notifications that are provided about the keyboard:

From: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html

> Keyboard Notifications
>
> When the system shows or hides the
>   keyboard, it posts several keyboard
>   notifications. These notifications
>   contain information about the
>   keyboard, including its size, which
>   you can use for calculations that
>   involve moving views. Registering for
>   these notifications is the only way to
>   get some types of information about
>   the keyboard. The system delivers the
>   following notifications for
>   keyboard-related events:
>
> ```
> * UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
> * UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
> * UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
> * UIKeyboardDidHideNotification
> ```
>
> For more information about these
>   notifications, see their descriptions
>   in UIWindow Class Reference. For
>   information about how to show and hide
>   the keyboard, see Text and Web.

Comment: I checked these notification, but don't know how to check these notifications. If you could post some example,that would be very helpful.

Comment: Have a look at NSNotificationCenter. You'll have to register for the notifications you're interested in. Don't forget to unregister when your application exits.

Answer (score 16):

**Add an extension**

```
extension UIApplication {
    /// Checks if view hierarchy of application contains `UIRemoteKeyboardWindow` if it does, keyboard is presented
    var isKeyboardPresented: Bool {
        if let keyboardWindowClass = NSClassFromString("UIRemoteKeyboardWindow"),
            self.windows.contains(where: { $0.isKind(of: keyboardWindowClass) }) {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

**Then check if keyboard is present,**

```
if UIApplication.shared.isKeyboardPresented {
     print("Keyboard presented")
} else { 
     print("Keyboard is not presented")
}
```

Comment: Can do `guard let keyboardWindowClass = NSClassFromString("UIRemoteKeyboardWindow") else { return false }; return UIApplication.shared.windows.contains(where: { $0.isKind(of: keyboardWindowClass) })`

Comment: Always return true when app have social login like facebook, google

Comment: it is no longer works for iOS16+

Answer (score 14):

**Swift 3 Implementation**

```
    import Foundation
class KeyboardStateListener: NSObject
{
    static let shared = KeyboardStateListener()
    var isVisible = false

    func start() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }

    func didShow()
    {
        isVisible = true
    }

    func didHide()
    {
        isVisible = false
    } 
}
```

Comment: I recommend removing the observer in deinit or if its a view controller in view willdisappear

Comment: There's no point in using a deinit if this is a singleton because it will never be deinited

Answer (score 12):

Using the window subview hierarchy as indication for keyboard showing is a hack. If Apple changers their underlying implementation all these answers would break.

The correct way would be to monitor Keyboard show and hide notifications application wide such as inside your App Delegate:

In AppDelegate.h:

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL keyboardIsShowing;

@end
```

In AppDelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    // Monitor keyboard status application wide
    self.keyboardIsShowing = NO;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

    return YES;
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    self.keyboardIsShowing = YES;
}

- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    self.keyboardIsShowing = NO;
}
```

Then you can check using:

```
BOOL keyboardIsShowing = ((AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).keyboardIsShowing;
```

It should be noted the keyboard show/hide notifications will not fire when user is using a bluetooth or external keyboard.

Answer (score 6):

This is from the iOS Text Programming Guide published by Apple here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html

Basically call "registerForKeyBoardNotifications" in your ViewDidLoad.  Then every time the keyboard becomes active, "keyboardWasShown" is called.  And every time the keyboard disappears, "keyboardWillBeHidden" is called.

```
// Call this method somewhere in your view controller setup code.
- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

// Called when the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is sent.
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification {
    NSLog(@"Keyboard is active.");
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    // If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
    // Your app might not need or want this behavior.
    CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
    aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeField.frame.origin) ) {
        [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:activeField.frame animated:YES];
    }
}

// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification {
    NSLog(@"Keyboard is hidden");
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Now in iOS8 this solution of course doesn't work.
It was written initially for IOS4/5.

Try this solution:

```
- (BOOL) isKeyboardOnScreen 
{
    BOOL isKeyboardShown = NO;

    NSArray *windows = [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows;
    if (windows.count > 1) {
        NSArray *wSubviews =  [windows[1]  subviews];
        if (wSubviews.count) {
            CGRect keyboardFrame = [wSubviews[0] frame];
            CGRect screenFrame = [windows[1] frame];
            if (keyboardFrame.origin.y+keyboardFrame.size.height == screenFrame.size.height) {
                isKeyboardShown = YES;
            }
        }
    }

    return isKeyboardShown;
}
```

Comment: It's invalid to assume that multiple windows implies a keyboard, and that the keyboard always the second element.

Comment: @jmah Of course it is not the universal approach but it covers huge amount of application cases. Any try to get info about keyboard use some specific view hierarchy because Apple doesn't provide any useful API for this case.

Comment: This does not works, what worked for me was iterate through all views and for all UITextFields or UITextView check if they are first responders...if any of then return true keyboard is visible else its not

Answer (score 5):

A few observations:

The recommended pattern for a singleton object would be as follows. dispatch_once makes sure the class is initialised once in a thread-safe way, and the static variable isn't visible outside. And it's standard GCD, so no need to know about low level details of Objective-C.

```
+ (KeyboardStateListener *)sharedInstance
{
    static KeyboardStateListener* shared;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        shared = [[KeyboardStateListener alloc] init];
        // Other initialisations
    });

    return shared;
}
```

Usually you don't want to know just whether the keyboard is visible or not, but how big it is. Keyboards don't all have the same size. iPhone keyboards are smaller than iPad keyboards. So you'd want another property `@property (readonly, nonatomic) CGRect keyboardRect;` which is set in the noticeShowKeyboard: method like this:

```
NSValue* value = notification.userInfo [UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];
_keyboardRect = value.CGRectValue;
```

Important to notice that the rectangle is in UIWindow coordinates and doesn't respect screen rotation. So the caller would convert that rectangle by calling

```
KeyboardStateListener* listener = [KeyboardStateListener sharedInstance];
CGRect windowRect = listener.keyboardRect;
CGRect viewRect = [myView convertRect:windowRect fromView:self.window];
```

If the user rotates the screen while the keyboard is visible, the app will be told that the keyboard is hidden, then shown again. When it is shown, other views are most likely not rotated yet. So if you observe keyboard hide/show events yourself, convert the coordinates when you actually need them, not in the notification.

If the user splits or undocks the keyboard, or uses a hardware keyboard, the notifications will always show the keyboard as hidden. Undocking or merging the keyboard will send a "keyboard shown" notification.

The listener must be initialised while the keyboard is hidden, otherwise the first notification will be missed, and it will be assumed that the keyboard is hidden when it's not.

So it is quite important to know what you actually want. This code is useful to move things out of the way of the keyboard (with a split or undocked keyboard, that's the responsibility of the user). It doesn't tell you whether the user can see a keyboard on the screen (in case of a split keyboard). It doesn't tell you whether the user can type (for example when there is a hardware keyboard). Looking at other windows doesn't work if the app creates other windows itself.

Comment: Good warnings about keyboard in iPad, thanx!

Answer (score 4):

**Swift** implementation:

```
class KeyboardStateListener: NSObject
{
  static var shared = KeyboardStateListener()
  var isVisible = false

  func start() {
    let nc = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
    nc.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didShow), name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
    nc.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didHide), name: UIKeyboardDidHideNotification, object: nil)
  }

  func didShow()
  {
    isVisible = true
  }

  func didHide()
  {
    isVisible = false
  } 
}
```

Because swift doesn't execute class **load** method on startup it is important to start this service on app launch:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool
{
  ...    
  KeyboardStateListener.shared.start() 
}
```

Comment: Using iOS 13, swift 5.0 this last bit, the class load doesn't seem to be necessary?

Answer (score 3):

This is my solution, it encapsulates everything into a single static method, and you can call it anywhere to check:

```
+(BOOL)isKeyboardVisible{
    static id tokenKeyboardWillShow = nil;
    static id tokenKeyboardWillHide = nil;
    static BOOL isKbVisible = NO;
    @synchronized (self) {
        if (tokenKeyboardWillShow == nil){
            tokenKeyboardWillShow = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification * _Nonnull note) {
                @synchronized (self) {
                    isKbVisible = YES;
                }
            }];
        }

        if (tokenKeyboardWillHide == nil){
            tokenKeyboardWillHide = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification * _Nonnull note) {
                @synchronized (self) {
                    isKbVisible = NO;
                }
            }];
        }
    }

    return isKbVisible;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4**

```
extension UIViewController {
    func registerKeyboardNotifications() {
        let center = NotificationCenter.default
        center.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillBeShown(note:)), name: Notification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        center.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillBeHidden(note:)), name: Notification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }

    func removeKeyboardNotifications() {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)

    }

    @objc
    func keyboardWillBeShown(note: Notification) {}

    @objc
    func keyboardWillBeHidden(note: Notification) {}

}

final class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Properties
    var isKeyboardVisible = false

    // MARK: - Life Cycle
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        registerKeyboardNotifications()
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        removeKeyboardNotifications()
    }

    // MARK: - Keyboard Handling
    override func keyboardWillBeShown(note: Notification) {
        isKeyboardVisible = true
        let userInfo = note.userInfo
        let keyboardFrame = userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! CGRect
        let contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardFrame.height, 0.0)
        tableView.contentInset = contentInset
    }

   override func keyboardWillBeHidden(note: Notification) {
        tableView.contentInset = .zero
        isKeyboardVisible = false
   }

   // MARK: - Test
   fileprivate func test() {
        if isKeyboardVisible { // do something
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Works very well for me (Xcode 10.2, Swift4) just curious why no one upvoted this?

Comment: No, that does not work if the keyboard was already presented by a previous view controller .

Comment: Ideally there shouldn't be a case when keyboard presented by a previous controller as it will be dismissed as the responder will not be there in new one.

Answer (score 2):

And here's how to do it in Swift:

```
 func registerForKeyboardNotifications() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
        self,
        selector: "keyboardWasShown:",
        name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification,
        object: nil)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
        self,
        selector: "keyboardWillBeHidden:",
        name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification,
        object: nil)
}

func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification) {
    println("Keyboard was shown");
}

func keyboardWillBeHidden(notification: NSNotification) {
    println("Keyboard was dismissed");
}
```

Don't forget to unregister:

```
 override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self,
        name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification,
        object: nil)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self,
        name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification,
        object: nil)
}
```

And if you want to dismiss keyboard on pressing the "Return" button:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var yourTextField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    registerForKeyboardNotifications()
    yourTextField.delegate = self
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {
    self.view.endEditing(true);
    return false;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this function

```
BOOL UIKeyboardIsVisible(){

BOOL keyboardVisible=NO;
// Locate non-UIWindow.
UIWindow *keyboardWindow = nil;
for (UIWindow *testWindow in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) {
    if (![[testWindow class] isEqual:[UIWindow class]]) {
        keyboardWindow = testWindow;
        break;
    }
}
// Locate UIKeyboard.
for (UIView *possibleKeyboard in [keyboardWindow subviews]) {
    // iOS 4 sticks the UIKeyboard inside a UIPeripheralHostView.
    if ([[possibleKeyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHostView"]) {
        keyboardVisible=YES;
    }
    if ([[possibleKeyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIKeyboard"]) {
        keyboardVisible=YES;
        break;
    }
}
return keyboardVisible;
```

}

from: [iOS: How to access the `UIKeyboard`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457239/ios-how-to-access-the-uikeyboard)

Answer (score 1):

BOOL isTxtOpen = [txtfieldObjct isFirstReponder]. If it returns YES, then the the keyboard is active.

Answer (score 1):

To check weather keyboard is appeared, we can use the Keyboard predefined notifications.

UIKeyboardDidShowNotification ,UIKeyboardDidHideNotification

For example I can use the following code to listen the keyboard notification

// Listen for keyboard appearances and disappearances

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                                           object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

in the methods I can get notifications

```
- (void)keyboardDidShow: (NSNotification *) notifyKeyBoardShow{
    // key board is closed
}

- (void)keyboardDidHide: (NSNotification *) notifyKeyBoardHide{
    // key board is opened
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**SwiftUI** - Full Example

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var text = defaultText
    
    @State private var isKeyboardShowing = false
    
    private static let defaultText = "write something..."
    
    private var gesture = TapGesture().onEnded({_ in
        UIApplication.shared.endEditing(true)
    })
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            Color.black
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                TextField("placeholder", text: $text)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.green)
            }
            
            .padding()
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        .onChange(of: isKeyboardShowing, perform: { (isShowing) in
            if isShowing {
                if text == Self.defaultText { text = "" }
            } else {
                if text == "" { text = Self.defaultText }
            }
        })
        .simultaneousGesture(gesture)
        .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default
                    .publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification), perform: { (value) in
                        isKeyboardShowing = true
                    })
        .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default
                    .publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification), perform: { (value) in
                        isKeyboardShowing = false
                    })
    }
}

extension UIApplication {
    func endEditing(_ force: Bool) {
        self.windows
            .filter{$0.isKeyWindow}
            .first?
            .endEditing(force)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iteratively check all textviews, textfields, and labels in the subviews of  a parent view to see if any are the first responder with something like this:

```
-(BOOL)isKeyboardActiveInView:(UIView *)view {
    for (UIView *anyView in [view subviews]) {
        if ([anyView isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            if (((UITextField *)anyView).isFirstResponder) {
                return YES;
            }
        } else if ([anyView isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
            if (((UILabel *)anyView).isFirstResponder) {
                return YES;
            }
        } else if ([anyView isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]]) {
            if (((UITextView *)anyView).isFirstResponder) {
                return YES;
            }
        } else {
            if ([self isKeyboardActiveInView:anyView]) {
                return YES;
            }
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: That fails if you have child view controllers

Answer (score -1):

**SWIFT 4.2 / SWIFT 5**

```
class Listener {
   public static let shared = Listener()
   var isVisible = false

   // Start this listener if you want to present the toast above the keyboard.
   public func startKeyboardListener() {
      NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
      NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
   }

   @objc func didShow() {
     isVisible = true
   }

    @objc func didHide(){
       isVisible = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score -5):

I think this may help u,

```
+(BOOL)isKeyBoardInDisplay  {

    BOOL isExists = NO;
    for (UIWindow *keyboardWindow in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows])   {
        if ([[keyboardWindow description] hasPrefix:@"<UITextEffectsWindow"] == YES) {
            isExists = YES;
        }  
    }

    return isExists;
}
```

thanks,

Naveen Shan

Comment: On iOS 6, Only works hasn't appeared yet! Once they keyboard has been showed once, its stop working.