# how to fix this function to move textfield when keyboard is presented in scrollview

Tags: swift

So i have this function to move the `TextField` in `ScrollView` but the problem is some `TextField` on top sometimes move too far when the `keyboard` is presented

Here is my code :

```
 func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        moveTextFIeld(textField: textField, moveDistance: -20, up: true)
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        moveTextFIeld(textField: textField, moveDistance: -20, up: false)
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {


        tanggalLahirTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}

    func moveTextFIeld(textField:UITextField,moveDistance:Int,up:Bool){
        let moveDuration = 0.3
        let movement : CGFloat = CGFloat(up ? moveDistance : -moveDistance)
        UIView.beginAnimations("animateTextField", context: nil)
        UIView.setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState(true)
        UIView.setAnimationDuration(moveDuration)
        self.view.frame = self.view.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: movement)
//        self.view.frame=CGRect.offsetBy(self.view.frame,0,movement)
        UIView.commitAnimations()


    }
```

Comment: Try [IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager)

Comment: yup use any keyboard avoiding lib. like IQWKeyboardManager

Comment: Possibly Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26689232/scrollview-and-keyboard-swift https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13161666/how-do-i-scroll-the-uiscrollview-when-the-keyboard-appears?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

we can use IQKeyboardManager from cocoapods.[Click here](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager/tree/master/IQKeyboardManagerSwift)