# Preventing keyboard cover AdBannerView and toolbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, keyboard

I added the AdBannerView and toolbar to my IOS drag and drop from object library i get problem because it is on fixed position under my UIwebview when I click on my webview to type it will cover AdBannerView just I want to ask how can I fix the problem[image]

the keyboard cover the AdBannerView and toolbar
[image]

Comment: How do you want that to be fixed? I mean, are you hoping to slide the banner and the toolbar up together with the keyboard?

Comment: yes this is my Im looking slide the adbanner and the toolbar up together

Comment: @Till do you have any idea how to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you listen to the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification notification, and resize the view or move the adbanner view accordingly.

see how to do that in the following question:

[How to detect when keyboard is shown and hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374436/how-to-detect-when-keyboard-is-shown-and-hidden)