# How can an iOS app know if a keyboard is already on the screen when the app opens (iOS Multitasking)

Tags: ios, ios9, multitasking, split-screen-multitasking, split-screen

How can an iOS app know if a keyboard is already on the screen when the app opens? Once an app is running, it can receive keyboard show/hide notifications. But if the app opens as a secondary app in Split Screen mode while the primary app already has a keyboard showing, the secondary app does not receive any notifications to tell it to adjust its views for the keyboard. And as far as I can tell, these notifications are the only way to tell if a keyboard is showing and what its frame is, to then obtain the necessary layout constraints. Is there a way to get this information, or should a bug report be filed for this issue?

Comment: Questions like this is what StackOverflow is about. I like it.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: No, I'm sorry, I haven't found a solution. I've tabled the issue for now.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to detect if another app has the keyboard focus.

You might be able to make a workaround using [Auto Layout](http://effortlesscode.com/auto-layout-keyboard-shown-hidden/) though.

or this [How to detect when keyboard is shown and hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374436/how-to-detect-when-keyboard-is-shown-and-hidden)

Comment: It looks from my feed that you might have started to answer this by saying that the keyboard is auto-hidden each time the app goes into split screen mode. I see the beginning of that answer in my feed but I can't find the answer on this page. Is that the case?

Comment: The keyboard is auto hidden, but if the keyboard was active in the first app, it will come back (still active in the first app) once the second has loaded. I just tried it on the iPad Pro simulator in XCode.

Comment: I don't think it comes back with any notifications, am I correct?

Comment: I don't see how it could. The notification, if any, would go to where the keyboard has focus (the app that was open already)

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374436/how-to-detect-when-keyboard-is-shown-and-hidden

Comment: it might have the answer for you