# ios eiditing a table, keyboard hide the field

Tags: ios, uitableview, keyboard, hide

I have this problem.. I have a view that contains a uitableview with each column is on a different row (is to editing a row, like the address book for example)
everything is ok, but if I click on the last field on the bottom, the keyboard appears, but appear over the field and I can't see nothing....

how can I solve this thing?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You may need to know [whether the keyboard is showing up or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490573/how-to-programatically-check-whether-a-keyboard-is-present-in-iphone-app).
2. Register for a few notifications:

   ```
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                            selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                                name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                            selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                                name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                            selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                                name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                            selector:@selector(keyboardWasHidden:)
                                                name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];
   ```
3. Scroll the row in tableview to a visible position in the listeners: `keyboardWillShow` `keyboardWasShown` `keyboardWillHide` `keyboardWasHidden`.