# Getting size of UITextField inputAccessoryView programmatically

Tags: cocoa-touch

I would like to determine the height of the inputAccessoryView that is showing with the current keyboard. I could probably track back through the firstResponder, if I need to, but I am looking for something more direct. If the keyboard is showing with an inputAccessoryView, return its height, otherwise return zero.

I am using keyboard notifications to help get the keyboard size, [based on the code shown in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490573/how-to-programatically-check-whether-a-keyboard-is-present-in-iphone-app). Once I know the keyboard is showing, I want to get info on the input accessory view.