# Integrated Form Doesn't Move When Text Fields Are Selected

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

I have embedded a ScrollView within a UIViewController which contains multiple text fields that will act as a simple form to collect user data (Name, email, etc.). The problem is that when a text field is selected and the keyboard slides up, the text field is obscured by the keyboard. How can I slide the text fields back into view so that the user can clearly see what they are using as input?

Comment: chekc this tutorial :-http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/sliding-uitextfields-around-to-avoid.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check for uikeyboard visibility ( see this post [How can I programmatically check whether a keyboard is present in iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490573/how-to-programatically-check-whether-a-keyboard-is-present-in-iphone-app) ) and then call scrollRectToVisible for the selected textField. If you google about uikeyboard and scrollRectToVisible you will find many tutorial about this problem...