# Detect UIPopover resize event

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uipopover

In iOS I am displaying some content within a `UIView` in a `UIPopover`.  Sometimes the popover resizes when the keyboard is shown.  Is there a specific event for the `UIView` that I can use to resize the subviews etc?  If not, what is the best way to detect the resize event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably have to detect this in a delegate method of what ever calls up the keyboard, for example if it's a `UITextField` something like `- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField`

Another option as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1492436/716216) is to use a `UIKeyboardListener` to list for notifications about wether or not the keyboard is visible.

`UIPopoverController` unfortunately only has two delegate methods and they pertain to the pop over dismissing.

```
 - (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController
   *)popoverController
 - (BOOL)popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
```