# Keyboard Hide/Show check in iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I am working on custom table cell, which have some textfields. on some button press method i dynamically add/remove row. But when Keyboard is shown on the screen and button is pressed then application crashes.

Comment: What are the crash logs? Code which is crashing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the very simple two lines method to solve the issue

First write a Bool isKeyBoardHide.

Then in ViewDidLoad Write this code

```
// Listen for keyboard appearances and disappearances
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                                           object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

Write these two methods to update bool about current status

```
- (void)keyboardDidShow: (NSNotification *) notif{
    isKeyBoardHide = NO;
}

- (void)keyboardDidHide: (NSNotification *) notif{
    isKeyBoardHide = YES;
}
```

When you want to check just implement that code

```
if(!isKeyBoardHide) {
// Dismiss Keyboard
[self.view endEditing:YES] 
} else {

//keyboard is already hidden
}
```

Very simple and easy way to solve this crash.

Comment: What is new then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490573/how-to-programatically-check-whether-a-keyboard-is-present-in-iphone-app ?