# iphone - Get dynamically created UITextField by tag

Tags: iphone, dynamic, uitextfield, tags

I add a UITextField to a table cell dynamically in my app. I'd like to implement a "backgroundClick" method to dismiss the keyboard if the user presses outside the textfield (and outside the keyboard) but I'm unsure how to get a handle on the active keyboard in the backgroundClick method as the dynamic UITextField does not have a defined property to use.

All I know is that it is a UITextField with a particular tag. Is there some way to get a hold of it in code?

Cheers.

Comment: For the benefit of future readers I used the below link offered by Benjamin to fix the problem. I set up a dummy UITextField which I bound to the UITextField I had dynamically added to my grouped table.
I was then able to call the following code to dismiss the keyboard at any other point in my code:
<code>
[dummyField becomeFirstResponder];
[dummyField resignFirstResponder];
</code>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UITextField* field =  (UITextField *) [myTableCell viewWithTag: myTag];
[field resignFirstResponder];
```

Is that what you are seeking?

**Edit to reflect comments:**

Based on your comment, it's not.  So, you probably want to read [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741185/easy-way-to-dismiss-keyboard).

Comment: it's close, the problem is that i don't have a handle on the table cell either. i dynamically populate cells based on a parameter. to one of the cells i add a uitextfield but i wanted to be able to dismiss it with a click outside the cell and outside the keyboard (essentially using a large, invisible button). the problem i have is that the button press event doesn't have information on the cell or the textfield. i'm starting to think that maybe this isn't possible.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a reference to the UITextField, then you can send resignFirstResponder. That will dismiss the keyboard.