# Dismissing the First Responder/Keyboard with multiple Textfields

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextfield, first-responder

Like seriously after going through this...

[Easy way to dismiss keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741185/easy-way-to-dismiss-keyboard)

... I have multiple `TextFields` and a few `TextViews`. Is there not a way to a have a batch or group Dismiss First Responder for all text fields? Will I need to make method for each field? Maybe I overlooked something in that link?

Maybe I can follow something like this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282837/problem-with-multiple-textfields-to-make-the-keyboard-dissapear

Would the latter make sense? Thanks in advance.

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-

I figured it out....

```
Controller.h

@interface Controller : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UITextField *clickedDone;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *clickedDone;

Controller.m

#import "Controller.h"
@implementation Controller
@synthesize clickedDone;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [clickedDone setDelegate:self];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;    
}
```

Comment: Only one field is the first responder, you only have to resign that one.

Comment: The link to the other SO question is dead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
clickedDone.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;  // in viewDidLoad

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField 
{
   [textField resignFirstResponder];
   return YES;    
}
```

Answer (score 31):

The view has an `endEditing:` method you can use. The docs say

> Causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the first responder status.

In your view controller you can just call:

```
[[self view] endEditing:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks! You solution is the best, specially when there are a lot of fields to deal with.

Answer (score 2):

Its very easy now. You can follow different approach depending on your use cases. In my case I had multiple textfields in UITableViewController. What I did is this :

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Best answer is:

1. Added UITextFieldDelegate protocol to your viewcontroller @interface
   ViewController : UIViewController
2. In your xib, select the textField, in your Ulitlites section in the right
   side pane of XCode in the subsection of "Connections Inspector",
   link the textField's delegate with the .xib's "File's Owner".
3. In your Viewcontroller implementation, include the follwing

---

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField 
{
   [textField resignFirstResponder];
   return YES;    
}
```