# How to programmatically change keyboard in iOS?

Tags: ios, keyboard

I would like to programmatically change keyboard when I click a button event.

I used custom keyboard in my app, but I need to change English (US) keyboard in programmatically when I click a button on my custom keyboard.

Comment: What do you mean by custom keyboard? Which one?

Comment: I means custom keyboard with UIView and UIButton.

Comment: And now you want to bring up the native keyboard? Or change your custom keyboard to a different language? If so, please link to that module so that we can see what it can do.

Comment: Yes i want to change native keyboard when i click button.

Comment: is there anyways to do like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just got my answer for my own question.

Just put `nil` into `inputView` and that will change back into English (US) Keyboard.

Comment: Hello, I have the same problem, what do you mean by inputType?

Comment: I figured it out, yourTextfield.inputView = nil;

Comment: Does this works just because your base language of the phone is English? What about if i have the Hindi language set as main phone's language and i want to set the English keyboard?

Answer (score 3):

The only way you can control the keyboard is by showing it (By setting a UITextView/UITextField as a first responder), hiding it (by resigning the editing [Easy way to dismiss keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741185/easy-way-to-dismiss-keyboard)).

The language of the keyboard cannot be changed by your app, since it is a user preference. If you want a custom keyboard of your own, you would have to design it yourself (with UIButtons) and obviously also program it (when it shows, when it hides. I would simply use the keyboard that the user prefers, why do you need to change it? After all, the user is the one that decides which keyboard he uses.

Answer (score -4):

You can change to the English (US) keyboard programmatically.

Try this:

```
textfield.secureTextEntry=YES;
textfield.secureTextEntry=NO;
```