# iOS Keyboard Customization

Tags: ios, uikeyboard

Hi Im asking if there is a way that let me force the user to use only one keyboard even if the user had more then  two or three languages in his system keyboard, for an example i want my user when he open the app he will find the english keyboard  only and not be able to switch it to another language ? in Swift 2.0 xcode 7

Comment: You can find more details on this [Thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22061402/change-language-in-the-app-programmatically) and [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644301/how-to-programatically-change-keyboard-in-ios). Hope Helps

Comment: @JohnMalkovich ,Thank you bro, I will take a look

Comment: What are you trying to do? Just prevent non-English characters from being entered?

Comment: Yes Sir , exactly I want to force user to use English keyboard only