# Dismiss the keyboard when the view is hidden

Tags: ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Easy way to dismiss keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741185/easy-way-to-dismiss-keyboard)

In `view1`, the keyboard gets shown. I want to dismiss the keyboard when i move to another view (`view2`).
In `view2`, in the method that gets called when the view is shown, i try to do so:

```
[self endEditing:YES];
```

But this doesn't work, so i get the idea of catching the event (in `View1`) of a hidden view and dismiss the keyboard before moving to `view2`. Is this possible?

**EDIT:**

I think i need to clarify that `view2` is not fully hidden when `view1` is shown. It's 50 shown vertically.

As long as i work on `view1`, the Keyboard is shown and `view2` is also shown (50%). `view2` has a button, when i click on that button, i need to dismiss the keyboard (which is shown from `view1`).

I tried to mplement a method in view1 like so:

```
-(void)dismissKeyBoard{

[self endEditing:YES];
}
```

And call the method above in `view2` when i click on the button but it doesn't work.

PS: The button i click in `view2` will make `view2` shows fully (100%) above `view1`.

Comment: This is possible. Can you describe how you move to another view?

Comment: can you have pointer to view1 from view2. Like [view2.view1.someTextField resignFirstResponder];?

Answer (score 0):

To dismiss the keyboard, you just have to "resignFirstResponder" on the input field that it is currently in. One easy way is to have a catch all method of all the input fields in your view.

So for example, I usually create a method like this:

```
-(void)dismissKeyboard {
  [self.textfield1 resignFirstResponder];
  [self.textfield2 resignFirstResponder];
}
```

then just call it before you transition

```
[self dismissKeyboard]
```

Comment: Hi, Thanx for you reply, problem is that view 2 is not fully hidden before transition, it's 50% shown. So the transition is not thrown from view1, but from view2 button.