# Objective-c EKEventEditViewController Dismiss keyboard

Tags: objective-c, ekevent

I'm presenting an EKEventEditViewController that I need for inserting an event into the calendar. All is fine, but how do I dismiss programmatically the keyboard when I go picking a date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is an old post but still didn't answered.I have been in this situation.So,like to share how to do it.

```
- (void)calendarMonthView:(TKCalendarMonthView *)monthView didSelectDate:(NSDate *)d {
}
```

Inside this method you can put `[textView resignFirstResponder]`.This will dismiss keyword while changing date.If you want to dismiss it at the beginning ..just use `[textView resignFirstResponder]` before calling calendar method .

Hope this will help others.

this is also a nice answer by kirby,you can try this too.

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

Courtesy:-https://stackoverflow.com/a/3705527/1865424