# how to resignFirstResponder from view controller

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8, resignfirstresponder

How to resignFirstResponder from uiviewcontroller object with is active.

I have five textfields one,two,three,four,five.

```
   - (void)removeKeyBoard{
     [one resignFirstResponder];
     [two resignFirstResponder];
     [three resignFirstResponder];
     [four resignFirstResponder];
     [five resignFirstResponder];
    }
```

The above code has done my job, but each object reference to specify for resignFirstResponder.

Is there any way, that handle the resignFirstResponser which ever field is active on `UIViewController` automatically resign that object.

@All 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easy way to dismiss keyboard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/741185/easy-way-to-dismiss-keyboard)

Comment: [self.view endEditing:true];

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Called on whatever view has the textfields in it:

`[view endEditing:YES]`

`UIView` reference: [Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html)

Comment: So its dismissed keyboard appears on screen, with respective any textfield                                            - (void)removeKeyBoard{ [view endEditing:YES]};

Comment: If we have have a scroll view on the screen, a view inside scroll view, then we have to keep the reference of inner view to endEditing.

Answer (score -2):

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: This post has no accompanying text or explanation as to how it answers the question. Would you add an introductory paragraph? Thanks.

Comment: Further to my earlier feedback, a number of your answers have needed repair (code with no formatting) and all except one are code only, which in general we do not encourage.

Comment: Your code will allow you to dismiss the keyboard when the user ends editing, but that's not what the OP is asking for. The OP asked how to unconditionally dismiss the keyboard (regardless of which text field is active.)