# How do I dismiss the number pad keyboard?

Tags: swift, xcode, label, numpad

In Xcode I selected the Number Pad under Keyboard Type for a label. It works fine, but I cannot dismiss the keyboard and it's blocking important content. How do I get the number pad to close?

Comment: Hard to say the best method without seeing some code or detail, but this thread has many answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741185/easy-way-to-dismiss-keyboard

Comment: There really isn't much code. Just a label connected as an outlet

Comment: What specifically is "label"? Because `UILabel` doesn't generally have a keyboard associated with it. Is it a `UITextField`? Did you check out the answers in the link I posted?

Comment: you can use IQKeyboardManager instead of normal keyboard  install it using ** pod IQKeyboardManager**

Answer (score 0):

you can use to dismiss the keyboard

```
view.endEditing(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
     let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIInputViewController.dismissKb))

    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

@objc func dismissKb() {
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```